# How to fetch the value inside a json file for linux

Tags: shell-script, json

I have an data which i am trying to fetch various method and the result is

```
[
"created:Alpha;DateCreated:12/12/2022;TicketNo:XXXX_XXX;ProductName:websphere;OStype:Linux"
]
```

I want to fetch the ostype as `Linux` from the above i tried to use `JQ` and no luck. any suggestions

Thanks

Raj

Comment: What did you try with `jq`? It might be easier to correct something than to solve the whole problem for you. And you get to really show your research ;).

Answer (score 1):

It would be so much easier if your data looked like this:

```json
[
  {
    "created": "Alpha",
    "DateCreated": "12/12/2022",
    "TicketNo": "XXXX_XXX",
    "ProductName": "websphere",
    "OStype": "Linux"
  }
]
```

From this, we could pick out the value of the `OStype` key in the first element of the top-level array using `jq` as so:

```bash
jq -r 'first.OStype'
```

So how do we get your data into that more manageable form? Well, we start by splitting the strings in your array on semi-colons, and then again on colons:

```bash
$ jq -r 'map(split(";"))' file
[
  [
    "created:Alpha",
    "DateCreated:12/12/2022",
    "TicketNo:XXXX_XXX",
    "ProductName:websphere",
    "OStype:Linux"
  ]
]
```

```bash
$ jq 'map(split(";")|map(split(":")))' file
[
  [
    [
      "created",
      "Alpha"
    ],
    [
      "DateCreated",
      "12/12/2022"
    ],
    [
      "TicketNo",
      "XXXX_XXX"
    ],
    [
      "ProductName",
      "websphere"
    ],
    [
      "OStype",
      "Linux"
    ]
  ]
]
```

We then turn each of the sub-sub arrays into key-value pairs via the `from_entries` function (?) in `jq` after designating the first element as the `key` and the second element as the `value`, and see...

```bash
$ jq 'map(split(";")|map(split(":")) | map({key:.[0],value:.[1]})|from_entries)' file
[
  {
    "created": "Alpha",
    "DateCreated": "12/12/2022",
    "TicketNo": "XXXX_XXX",
    "ProductName": "websphere",
    "OStype": "Linux"
  }
]
```

Then either pipe that to the first `jq` command in the answer here or incorporate that into what we already have:

```bash
$ jq -r 'map(split(";")|map(split(":")) | map({key:.[0],value:.[1]})|from_entries) | first.OStype' file
Linux
```

Right, so that's useful if we wanted to convert all of your data into something more useful, possibly for other things than to pull a single value out of it. But what if we want to reach in and grab that `Linux` string without converting everything into nice-looking JSON objects?  We can do this easily enough with the list of lists of lists above, with a `select()` call. Just pick out the second element of the sub-sub array whose first element is the string `OSType`:

```bash
$ jq -r 'map(split(";")|map(split(":"))) | first[] | select(.[0] == "OStype")[1]' file
Linux
```

Or, if you have full control over the ordering of these strings and know the value you're looking for is the *last* value in that string of key-value pairs, meaning we don't have to go looking for it in all sub-sub arrays:

```bash
$ jq -r 'map(split(";")|map(split(":"))) | first[-1][1]' file
Linux
```

Or, if you want to use regular expressions, just capture the string after `OStype:` in your string:

```bash
$ jq -r 'map(capture("OStype:(?<OStype>[^;]+)")) | first.OStype' file
Linux
```

Anyway, that's if you want to do it with `jq`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to wrangle your input with pure `jq`:

```
$ jq '.[] / ";" | reduce .[] as $item ({}; . + ($item / ":" | {(.[0]): (.[1])}))' file
{
  "created": "Alpha",
  "DateCreated": "12/12/2022",
  "TicketNo": "XXXX_XXX",
  "ProductName": "websphere",
  "OStype": "Linux"
}
```

You can then extract the desired field directly:

```
jq -r '.[] / ";" | reduce .[] as $item ({}; . + ($item / ":" | {(.[0]): (.[1])})) | .OStype' file
Linux
```

Comment: It's not clear from the question, but since their top-level thing is an array, I'm assuming they may have multiples of these strings in the array (why else have an array?). I opted for always returning the _first_ string's `OStype`. You are returning _all_ of them. Not that there's anything wrong, mind. It's just a difference in assumptions in what they have and what they want.

Comment: Looks like brainfuck language ^^ Not sure about maintainability =)

Answer (score 0):

With just `Perl`:

```
$ perl -MJSON::XS -MFile::Slurp -E '
    my $json = read_file("json");
    $json = decode_json $json;
    $_ = $json->[0];
    s/.*OStype://;
    say
'
```

Return:

```
Linux
```

With [`gron`](https://github.com/tomnomnom/gron) and `GNU grep`:

```
$ gron file | grep -oP 'created:.*OStype:\K\w+'
Linux
```

With `gron` and `Perl`:

```
$ gron file | perl -nE 'say $& if /created:.*OStype:\K\w+/'
Linux
```

Or with `jq` and `GNU grep`:

```
$ jq '.[]' | grep -oP 'created:.*OStype:\K\w+'
```